# Hibernate Envers on MsSql server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm using spring - hibernate in my project and I'd like to add Envers in order to audit some of my tables. The configuration is very simple. I'm adding @Audited annotation to one of my table. The problem is the syntax of MsSql. When Hibernate creates the tables, the naming convention is [TABLE_NAME] but when Envers tries to create his tables the syntax is [TABLE_NAME]_AUD and it cause MsSqm syntax error.

In order to fix it, I've implemented my NamingStrategy class where I'm cutting off the []. Now _AUD table created properly but fails when I'm trying to save some entity (because of lack of braces I suppose).

The question is can I overwrite the Envers naming strategy somehow? Changin suffix won't help obviously.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try changing the prefix?

Comment: No I didn't....I guess prefix would be generated in a same way PREF_[TABLE_NAME] so it will cause same error

Comment: Ah, ok, I guess I didn't understand the question really. I don't know MsSQL so I don't also know where the [] come from